# struggling in deploying machine learning classifier project

Tags: machine-learning, flask

Please and one can help me in this when i try to debug the web-app after i applied the machine learning algorithms (BagOfwords vectorization& classifiers) i have stragguled, and the error was like following:

```
  File "c:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\webapp\app2.py", line 42, in predict
    tweet_vect = words.transform([tweet]).toarray()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'transform'
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Apr/2023 11:29:54] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500
```

So my codes are as follow , ,model.py :

```
df = pd.read_csv ('C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\webapp\\df.csv')
df.head()

from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemma= WordNetLemmatizer()
stop = stopwords.words('English')
def clean_tweets(text):
    text = text.lower()
    words= nltk.word_tokenize(text)
# Lemmatization is another technique used to reduce inflected words to their root word. It describes the algorithmic process of identifying an inflected word's “lemma” (dictionary form) based on its intended meaning.
    words = ' '.join ([lemma.lemmatize(word) for word in words 
                     if word not in (stop)])
    text=''.join(words)
# removing non-alphabit characters
    text = re.sub('[^a-z]',' ',text)
    return text


# create a corpus:
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
df.head(10)
corpus  = []
pstem = PorterStemmer()
for i in range(df['cleaned_tweets'].shape[0]):
    tweet = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", ' ', df['cleaned_tweets'][i])
    #Transform words to lowercase
    tweet = tweet.split()
    #Remove stopwords then Stemming it
    tweet = [pstem.stem(word) for word in tweet if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    tweet = ' '.join(tweet) 
    #Append cleaned tweet to corpus
    corpus.append(tweet)

df = df.drop(['text'],axis=1)
print("Corpus created successfully") 
print(pd.DataFrame(corpus)[0].head(10))
rawTexData = df["cleaned_tweets"].head(10)
cleanTexData = pd.DataFrame(corpus, columns=['corpus'])
frames = [rawTexData, cleanTexData]
result = pd.concat(frames, axis=1, sort=False)
result

#Create our dictionary 
uniqueWordFrequents = {}
for tweet in corpus:
    for word in tweet.split():
        if(word in uniqueWordFrequents.keys()):
            uniqueWordFrequents[word] += 1
        else:
            uniqueWordFrequents[word] = 1
            
#Convert dictionary to dataFrame
uniqueWordFrequents = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(uniqueWordFrequents,orient='index',columns=['Word Frequent'])
uniqueWordFrequents.sort_values(by=['Word Frequent'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
uniqueWordFrequents.head(10)
uniqueWordFrequents['Word Frequent'].unique()
uniqueWordFrequents = uniqueWordFrequents[uniqueWordFrequents['Word Frequent'] >= 20]
print(uniqueWordFrequents.shape)
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
counVec = CountVectorizer(max_features = uniqueWordFrequents.shape[0])
bagOfWords = counVec.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()



b = bagOfWords
y = df['target']

print("b shape = ",b.shape)
print("y shape = ",y.shape)

b_train , b_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(b,y,test_size=0.20, random_state=55, shuffle =True)
print('data splitting successfully')
multinomialNBModel = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.1)
multinomialNBModel.fit(b_train,y_train)

print("multinomialNB model run successfully")

passModel=PassiveAggressiveClassifier()
passModel.fit(b_train,y_train)
print ('Passive Regressive model run successfully')

modelsNames = [('multinomialNBModel',multinomialNBModel),
               ('PassiveAggressiveClassifier',passModel)]

from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
votingClassifier = VotingClassifier(voting = 'hard',estimators= modelsNames)
votingClassifier.fit(b_train,y_train)
print("votingClassifier model run successfully")



models = [multinomialNBModel, passModel, votingClassifier]

for model in models:
    print(type(model).__name__,' Train Score is   : ' ,model.score(b_train, y_train))
    print(type(model).__name__,' Test Score is    : ' ,model.score(b_test, y_test))
    
    y_pred = model.predict(b_test)
    print(type(model).__name__,' F1 Score is      : ' ,f1_score(y_test,y_pred))

    

 
bagOfWords
import pickle
pickle.dump(votingClassifier, open("model.pkl", "wb"))
pickle.dump(bagOfWords, open("words.pkl", "wb"))
```

app2.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
from flask import redirect
from flask import url_for
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
import numpy as np
import joblib
nltk.download('stopwords')
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
ps = PorterStemmer()

model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
words = pickle.load(open('words.pkl', 'rb'))
       
# Build functionalities
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return render_template('index2.html')

def predict(text):
    tweet = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', text)
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    tweet = tweet.split()
    tweet = [ps.stem(word) for word in tweet if not word in stopwords.words('english')]
    tweet = ' '.join(tweet)
    tweet_vect = words.transform([tweet]).toarray()
    prediction = 'FAKE' if model.predict(tweet_vect) == 0 else 'REAL'
    return prediction
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def webapp():
    text = request.form['text']
    prediction = predict(text)
    return render_template('index2.html', text=text, result=prediction)
@app.route('/predict/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def api():
    text = request.args.get('text')
    prediction = predict(text)
    return jsonify(prediction=prediction)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

pls any help

Answer (score 0):

The error happens when the execution reaches this line in `app.py`:

```
tweet_vect = words.transform([tweet]).toarray()
```

Remember `transform` is one of the methods of the `CountVectorizer` class. Therefore, **if** the variable `words` stored such a class, this line *would have  worked*. Since it didn't, that's telling you the variable probably does not store a `CountVectorizer` instance :)

As a matter of fact, if you check how that variable was defined earlier on in `model.py` and then persisted, you'll find this line:

```
bagOfWords = counVec.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
```

Note that, in that expression, method `toarray` was the last one to be called, which means the value stored in `bagOfWords` was that method's output, **not** the actual `CountVectorizer` instance (which is the one that has the `transform` method, which is here lost).

That's why when you try to invoke that method on the object that was stored, the program couldn't find it.

This particular error can be solved by replacing this line in `model.py`:

```
bagOfWords = counVec.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
```

with

```
bagOfWords = counVec.fit_transform(corpus)
```

**but** I haven't analyzed all possible dependencies throughout the code and, if the value of that variable is meant to be used as an array somewhere else, you could be introducing new bugs so be careful with any modifications. Generally speaking, you always want to persist the whole `CountVectorizer` instance as that object, because it will be helpful later on for reproducibility.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you very much, it works